# javascript - Split a string by multiple control chracters using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble formating a string in javascript.  Ideallly I would like to split it but just replacing the control characters would be a bonus. The string contains multiple control characters which I can use to do the split or replace but cannot get the correct regex.

The string used for the split/replace is (hex) 0a 20 0a 20

I have tried this

```
tidy_summary = tidy_summary.replace(/[\x0a \x20 \x0a \x20 ]/g,'~');
```

and this

```
tidy_summary = tidy_summary.replace(/[\x0a|\x20\x0a|\x20]/g,'~');
```

but it returns multiple '~'

I would like to replace the sequence of four characters with one.

Any help appraciated

Comment: Add `+` quantifier on character class `.replace(/[\x0a|\x20\x0a|\x20]+/g, '~');`

Comment: Sorry, could you please provide an exact sample string (as a string literal) and expected output? Is it `"\x0a\x20\x0a\x20"`? Then use `.replace(/(?:\x0a\x20){2}/g, '~')`

Answer (score 1):

Your regexes match a single character at a time, not a sequence of chars.

The `[\x0a \x20 \x0a \x20 ]` regex matches 1 char that is either a newline or space. The `[\x0a|\x20\x0a|\x20]` pattern matches 1 char that is either a newline, a space or `|` symbol (as the alternation operator inside a character class matches the literal pipe symbol).

To match a *sequence* of chars, remove the unnecessary spaces/pipes and the character class `[` and `]`:

```js
var tidy_summary = "Line 1\x0a\x20\x0a\x20Record 2";
console.log(tidy_summary.replace(/\x0a\x20\x0a\x20/g,'~'));
// or a bit shorter with a limiting quantifier:
console.log(tidy_summary.replace(/(?:\x0a\x20){2}/g,'~'));
```

With `(?:\x0a\x20){2}` pattern, a double (due to `{2}` limiting quantifier) newline and space sequence (`(?:\x0a\x20)`) is matched. The `(?:...)`, a non-capturing group, is used to group the symbols as *sequences*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I am adding your code now.